# What's the difference between compilation debug="false" and Release mode?

Tags: asp.net, build, debugging, release

In ASP.NET, what's the difference between building a project with  in the Web.config and with Release mode in the Configuration Manager?

When would you use one and not the other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the best explanation that I found:

http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2005/11/15/debug-and-release-builds-in-asp-net-2-0.aspx

Answer (score 4):

ScottGu did a pretty good right up of the differences [here](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/442448) on his blog.

I typically use this mode when I need to do debugging inside of Visual Studio or if I'm trying to track down a particularly nasty bug.  So I usually run with debug mode to set to false.

Comment: Good information on debug="false", but doesn't address Release mode.

Comment: The mentioned link is gone by now.

Comment: I fixed the broken link to ScottGu's article.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you set up your web app (Web Site model vs Web Application model), you might be deploying un-compiled source code directly to the web server.  In that case, the ASP.Net runtime needs to know how you want your code compiled when requests start coming in.

Comment: So does Release mode pre-compile the entire app?

Answer (score 0):

When compiling in "Release" mode, the web.release.config file will be used, when compiling in debug mode the web.debug.config file will be used (which both extend web.config). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2791236/what-are-the-web-debug-config-and-web-release-config-files-for) for more information on those files.

These files may contain a section like this:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
    <!-- Lines removed for clarity. -->
</system.web>
```

In ASP.NET this setting controls whether bundling or minification is done to optimize page load time.

- Bundling means: Combine or bundle multiple files into a single file
  (to reduce the number of page requests).
- Minification means: Removing unnecessary white space and comments and shortening variable names to
  one character.

See [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification) for more information on bundling and minification.

The default value for the ´debug´ is false, so the optimatzions are enabled per default.