# Asp.Net web app built as Release, but web.config says Debug - what is the result?

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config

An ASP.Net application I work with is built on a build server in release mode, and then deployed to IIS.

However, in it's web.config file on the servers where it is running, it says

```
<compilation debug="true" .../>
```

Does that have any effect on how the application is being run or how it performs? My guess would be that the web.config setting only applies to server side compilations - but I don't actually know.

Comment: Build in release mode is useless. XML transformation only happens when you **publish/deploy** it in release mode, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/web-config-transformations#webconfig-transformations-versus-web-deploy-parameters

Comment: Thanks for the input. It doesn't seem to answer the question though. The binaries are built in release mode and it all works, I'm just curious about whether the web.config setting has any effect or not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between compilation debug="false" and Release mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939634/whats-the-difference-between-compilation-debug-false-and-release-mode)

Comment: One of the links in that post does seem to answer it, yes :-) I'll read it more carefully and eventually quote it here to answer my own question (unless you want to?) Thanks either way!